X11 socket stops responding after ChangeProperty request
I'm implementing an X11 client library in Zig, but for some reason the read end of my X11 socket seems to stop responding as soon as I send a ChangeProperty request.
Due to the scope of this project, I'm unfortunately unable to create a small test case, but I have the offending project posted to GitHub (richRemer/zig-x11demo) (q.v., especially, src/main.zig and src/x11.zig).
I'm connecting to the server over a Unix socket, and I'm using the Zig equivalent of the Linux poll function, passing -1 for timeout to wait forever:
/// Read the next message, if one is available, or wait until one becomes
/// available.
pub fn readOneWait(this: *Server) !void {
    _ = try this.readOneWithTimeout(-1); // unlimited
}

/// Read the next message, if one is available or becomes available before
/// the timeout.  A negative timeout will wait forever.  If a message is
/// read, the return value will be true.
pub fn readOneWithTimeout(this: *Server, timeout: i32) !bool {
    const pollfd = std.os.linux.pollfd;
    const POLL = std.os.linux.POLL;

    var pollfds = [1]pollfd{pollfd{
        .fd = this.connection.stream.handle,
        .events = POLL.IN | POLL.ERR | POLL.HUP,
        .revents = 0,
    }};

    if (std.os.linux.poll(&pollfds, pollfds.len, timeout) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (pollfds[0].revents & std.os.linux.POLL.ERR > 0) {
            log.err("socket poll error", .{});
            return error.X11SocketError;
        }

        if (pollfds[0].revents & std.os.linux.POLL.HUP > 0) {
            log.err("socket poll error", .{});
            return error.X11SocketError;
        }

        this.readMessage() catch {
            log.err("could not read message from socket", .{});
            return error.X11SocketError;
        };

        return true;
    }
}

/// Read the next pending message from the X11 server.  If the message is a
/// reply, the .reply_data field will be set.  If it is an error or event
/// and a handler has been registered, the message will be passed to the
/// handler.
/// TODO: confirm behavior when no data is available
fn readMessage(this: *Server) !void {
    const reader = this.connection.stream.reader();

    this.read_mutex.lock();
    defer this.read_mutex.unlock();

    const info = try reader.readStruct(GenericMessage);
    const code: io.Code = @enumFromInt(@intFromEnum(info.code) & 0x7f);
    const message: ?Message = switch (code) {
        .@"error" => Message{
            .@"error" = fromPtr(io.Error, &info),
        },
        .reply => blk: {
            const generic = fromPtr(GenericReply, &info);
            const generic_data = std.mem.asBytes(&generic);
            const data = try this.allocator.alloc(u8, generic.sizeOf());
            errdefer this.allocator.free(data);

            // write generic to data; copy extended bytes from socket
            @memcpy(data[0..@sizeOf(GenericReply)], generic_data);
            _ = try reader.readAll(data[@sizeOf(GenericReply)..]);
            // data now contains full reply with all related data

            if (this.reply_data != null) {
                @panic("did not clean up last reply");
            }

            this.reply_data = data;
            break :blk null; // null result won't trigger handler
        },
        .focus_in => Message{
            .focus_in = fromPtr(io.FocusInEvent, &info),
        },
        .focus_out => Message{
            .focus_out = fromPtr(io.FocusOutEvent, &info),
        },

        // ...snipped out other events...

        else => null,
    };

    if (message != null and this.handler != null) {
        this.handler.?(message.?, this.handler_context);
    }
}

Most requests so far have worked fine.  I'm able to complete the connection handshake and send InternAtom, CreateWindow, and MapWindow requests (among others) and get back expected replies.  The app has a loop that simply waits for the next server message and sends any errors or events to a handler that logs them:
while (context.running) try server.readOneWait();

But when I send the ChangeProperty request, the loop hangs waiting for the socket to respond.  The request is sent with:
pub fn changeProperty(
    this: *Server,
    comptime T: type,
    window_id: u32,
    property_id: u32,
    value: []const T,
) !void {
    if (T != u8 and T != u16 and T != u32) {
        @compileError("type must be u8, u16, or u32");
    }

    const format = @sizeOf(T) * 8;
    const data_len: u32 = @intCast(value.len);
    const mode = io.ChangePropertyMode.replace; // TOOD: support all modes
    const writer = this.connection.stream.writer();
    const data_size = data_len * @sizeOf(T);
    const data = @as([*]const u8, @ptrCast(value.ptr))[0..data_size];
    const padded = pad(usize, data.len);

    this.write_mutex.lock();
    defer this.write_mutex.unlock();

    try writer.writeStruct(io.ChangePropertyRequest{
        .mode = mode,
        .request_len = io.ChangePropertyRequest.requestLen(format, data_len),
        .window_id = window_id,
        .property_id = property_id,
        .type_id = none, // ignored? (docs say "uninterpreted")
        .format = format,
        .data_len = data_len,
    });

    try writer.writeAll(data);
    try writer.writeByteNTimes(0, padded - data.len);
}

I'm stumped on what I can try to debug the issue.  I can tell from debugging that I'm not getting any errors back.  Hopefully an X11 guru will be able to point me in the right direction.
